# Android libgdx wallpaper app throws NoClassDefFoundError error at startup

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I try to make livewallpaper with libgdx.

[image]

I make all like [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationConfiguration#Live_Wallpapers).

[image]

My ApplicationListener:

```
public class GdxTestActivity implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void render() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Livewallpaper.java:

```
public class LiveWallpaper extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService 
{
    @Override
    public ApplicationListener createListener (boolean isPreview) {
            return new GdxTestActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidApplicationConfiguration createConfig () {
            return new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public void offsetChange (ApplicationListener listener, float xOffset, float yOffset, float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep,
            int xPixelOffset, int yPixelOffset) {
            Gdx.app.log("LiveWallpaper", "offset changed: " + xOffset + ", " + yOffset);
    }
```

Why I see this errors when I load my application?

```
Link of class 'Lcom/example/gdxtest01/GdxTestActivity;' failed
Could not find class 'com.example.gdxtest01.GdxTestActivity', referenced from method com.example.gdxtest01.LiveWallpaper.createListener
VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 620 (Lcom/example/gdxtest01/GdxTestActivity;) in Lcom/example/gdxtest01/LiveWallpaper;
VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener;)
VFY: unable to resolve static field 726 (app) in Lcom/badlogic/gdx/Gdx;
Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidLiveWallpaper;' failed
Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaper', referenced from method com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaperService$AndroidWallpaperEngine.onCreate
VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 520 (Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidLiveWallpaper;) in Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidLiveWallpaperService$AndroidWallpaperEngine;
VFY: unable to resolve interface method 3145: Lcom/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener;.dispose ()V
Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidLiveWallpaper;' failed
...
Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidLiveWallpaper;' failed
VFY: unable to resolve instance field 1010
02-11 21:31:51.398: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaper
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidLiveWallpaperService$AndroidWallpaperEngine.onCreate(AndroidLiveWallpaperService.java:108)
at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:648)
at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:875)
at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After some [magic](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) all is fine.

Comment: What is in the `libs` directory of your main project?  Its odd that `AndroidLiveWallpaperService` is okay, but `AndroidLiveWallpaper` is not.  Is there anything else in the log before or after the exception that might be relevant?

Comment: @P.T.: See updated log and build path pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gdx.jar` from the main project isn't being included in the Android `.apk`.  (All the `com.badlogic.gdx.*` classes are in this jar file.)

See steps 4, 5, & 6 in the Manual project setup: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup#Android_project_setup

You're probably just missing the bit that marks "gdx.jar" as "exported".  Right-click on the project, select `Build Path` `->` `Configure Build Path ...`.  Select the `Order and Export` tab, make sure there is a check-mark next to "gdx.jar".

Comment: It's included. Thanks for answers! See my Build Path image.